# Swift how to give a uicollectionview automatic height?

Tags: swift

I want to give my uicollectionview automatic height.I found this code

```
self.flowLayout.estimatedItemSize = UICollectionViewFlowLayoutAutomaticSize
```

But it didn't tell what `flowLayout` is,so it didn't work

Comment: It seems confusing, you want to set a dynamic height for exactly what? the collectionview itself or the cell in the collectionview?

Comment: @AhmadF collectionview itself

Comment: you can do so by setting frame height of collectionView's content

Comment: How tall you want that collectionView to be?

Comment: @Phyber based on content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set its height like so:

```
collectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
collectionView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: collectionView.contentSize.height).isActive = true
```

Or by setting its frame:

```
collectionView.frame = CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: width, height: collectionView.contentSize.height)
```

Comment: `collectionView.contentSize.height` returns 0.0

Comment: in `viewdidload`

Comment: Put that inside `viewDidAppear`

Comment: Thanks for the answer papa Phyber